# Compare value between 2 threads in CUDA

Tags: cuda, synchronization, comparison

Consider all the threads in a block have an integer variable `a` with a value that may be different across threads. How to compare if the first thread in the block has the same value of `a` as the last thread in the block? I just need to compare these 2 threads because the value of `a` is non-decreasing along with the thread index.

Comment: Just have two words of shared memory and have each store its value, then have one threas compare the values stored in the two locations?

Comment: What is block size?

Comment: @Oblivion, it's 256 threads.

Comment: @SergeRogatch I think the best option is what talonmies suggested then. There is a better solution if you had only one warp in your block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with a block containing more than a warp, you have to use shared or global memory in which shared memory will be faster.
static shared memory can be used as the size is known:

```
// .. 
thread_block block = this_thread_block();
__shared__ int s[2];
__shared__ bool result;
uint32_t tid = threadIdx.x;

if(tid == 0)
    s[0] = a;
if(tid == blockDim.x - 1)
    s[1] = a;
block.sync(); // synchronize the block instead the whole grid

if(tid == 0)
    result = s[0] == s[1];
block.sync();
```

if the block had only a warp or if you had to compare the `a` from the first and last thread of a warp, there is a better solution with [cooperative groups](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cooperative-groups/)

```
#include <cooperative_groups.h>
namespace cg = cooperative_groups;

auto active = cg::coalesced_threads();
int theOtherA = active.shfl(a, active.size() -1); // everybody has a copy a from 
//last thread of the warp
bool result = a == theOtherA; // thread 0 has correct result
result = active.shfl(result, 0); // get a copy from the register of thread 0
```